# Why does adding a Console.CancelKeyPress handler block debugger CTRL+C exit when a Task is running

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I have managed to get this down to a minimal test case running in VS2017 with .Net Framework 4.6:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.CancelKeyPress += (o, e) => End(); //some attempt to exit gracefully
        Task.Run(() => Task.Delay(100000)).Wait();
    }

    private static void End()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("EXITING...");
    }
```

If I run this in the debugger with `Console.CancelKeyPress` commented out, CTRL+C force-terminates the application. With the code as written, it outputs "EXITING..." then hangs even though my event handler does nothing to prevent termination.

If I run from the command line, both versions exit as expected.

It took me some time to figure out the unfinished `Task` is involved but I have no idea why the event handler is changing the behaviour. Can anyone figure out why? Is it some debugger quirk? I see no errors in the debugger...

Comment: Can anyone confirm it? An online fiddle won't let you test CTRL+C

Comment: Reproduced. `Console.CancelKeyPress += null` triggers this behaviour as well.

Comment: I suspect simply calling [`SetConsoleCtrlHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolectrlhandler) affects this ([see here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/console.cs,1813))

Comment: Based on my search, I find that Console.CancelKeyPress will trigger event when you press 'CTRL+C'. Then,I am not sure why you comment out the code. Also, I don't understand what is force-terminates the application. It will be useful for you to solve the problem if you explain these two points.

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT test it yourself would be my advice.

Comment: I think you found a good case for bug report :)...

Comment: This is [known problem](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/735047/program-will-deadlock-when-cancel-an-task-in-conso.html).  They are not in a hurry to fix it, it doesn't look like a simple issue to me.  The OS appears to be involved, it also doesn't behave correctly without a debugger.  They have been tinkering heavily with the Win10 console sub-system to support WSL better, probably the root issue.  An OS patch or update is likely to be needed, that takes time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a visual studio debugger issue and I think it's happening because the visual studio is tracing all running threads separately and as you said you have an unfinished task running in another thread.

when you terminating your program from command-line using `CTRL+C`, the commandLine forcing your Main Thread to stop. this way your child thread will stop too but when you run your application using VS-debugger main thread is attached to the debugger.

by default, the debugger will release all blocking threads if you don't handle `Console.CancelKeyPress` event but not when you want to manually control terminate calls. ([I'm not sure why](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/735047/program-will-deadlock-when-cancel-an-task-in-conso.html))

if you want to force the debugger to terminate all threads you have to do this manually.

```cs
    private static void End()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("EXITING...");
      if (Debugger.IsAttached)
          Environment.Exit(1); // this is equal to using CTRL+C in the terminal
    }
```

also, you should use a cancelation token to cleanly cancel your running tasks before application termination.

```cs
 class Program
    {
        private static CancellationTokenSource tokenSource;
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var token = tokenSource.Token;
            Console.CancelKeyPress += (o, e) => End(); 
            await Task.Run(() => Task.Delay(100000), token);
        }

        private static void End()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("EXITING...");
            tokenSource.Cancel();
            tokenSource.Dispose();
            if (Debugger.IsAttached)
                Environment.Exit(1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You'd be better off using [`Debugger.IsAttached`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.isattached?view=netframework-4.8) surely?

Comment: `#if DEBUG` tests whether you have a Debug build, not whether there is a debugger attached. You can run Debug builds without a debugger attached, and you can attach a debugger to Release builds.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a wild guess, but have you checked what happens when you set the Cancel property of the [ConsoleCancelEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.consolecanceleventargs?view=netframework-4.8) instance **e** to false?

It would be weird if that would solve your problem, it may help narrow down the problem, though.

PS: I can't test it myself, as I'm currently on a Linux machine.